# Book - Three teenagers find a spaceship and gain powers from headsets in it

Tags: story-identification, novel, soft-sci-fi, nanotechnology

I’ve tried to search for this book using keywords and quotes on Google, but I couldn’t find it.

In this book, three teenagers, a boy and two girls, find a lost spaceship that was camouflaging itself. They find four headsets in the spaceship, and put the first three on. Over the next few days, they gain special powers from the alien ship.
The boy gets a kind of super strength. One of the girls gains the ability to do math super well, and the last girl... well I forgot. They all have exceptional strength and intelligence as a result of the headsets; its just that they have a specialty.

Another human, the antagonist in the story, had made a black hole, and theorized that the only way to get rid of it was to put it through a portal into another world, but he was under influence from some alien race, which were waiting at the other side of the portal to take over humanity. The three teenagers, with their superpowers and the training of some mentor, stop the aliens from taking over Earth, and also are able to shove the black hole through, destroying the aliens’ world. The girl whose power I didn’t know dies, though.

And also the aliens have nanobots in their bodies.

Comment: Do you remember when you may have read the book, it would help narrow down the possibilities

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are describing a book by Richard Phillips, "Second Ship", Book 1 of the Rho Agenda.

While I can't find a really good descriptive narrative (I did find [this synopsis](https://scifistandpoint.wordpress.com/tag/the-rho-agenda/)) to corroborate all the elements, enough fit that I think it's a good match.

- Hidden ship - Check.
- Teenagers - Check. Found by three teenagers
- New powers - Check. Technology in the ship changes the teenagers.
- Alien species - Check.

I couldn't find a description of the aliens or the powers, but given the bits and pieces I found in various summary blurbs, I think it is a good candidate.

Cover art (One version):

[image]

Comment: I was going to make this same reply when I saw the question. I am sure this is it. The Rho Agenda was a 3 book series. It was followed 
 by 2 more trilogies of the same setting and characters (9 total) https://www.fantasticfiction.com/p/richard-phillips/second-ship.htm

Comment: As far as I recall the last girl did not die. Her power was eidetic memory, she was able to catalog and organize everything she read and sort through it to find answers needed.

Comment: This was it, thank you!